# Designmodo's Startup Framework Kit with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, frameworks

I'm wondering if Designmodo's Startup Framework Kit can be integrated into my Ruby on Rails application. Their Flat-UI-Pro integrates nicely by using the gem. However, I couldn't find any for the Startup Framework. Does anybody know how to integrate the kit to RoR?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote this today. Should help you get started with Startup Framework on Rails. Let me know if you have any issues. Very nascent. Should work fine.

```
gem install designmodo-startup_framework-rails
```

Comment: Added another version named 1.1.3.7 where it is written in much stable and better format.

Comment: Help documentation available here: https://github.com/vertmac/designmodo-startup_framework-rails